# Can you revert the bronze stars to gold?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy-2

If I got a Bronze Star can I turn it back into a power star by doing something or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bronze Stars are created by using the Cosmic Spirit to complete an objective. They can be replaced with a regular Power Star simply by playing the objective again, and completing it without the Cosmic Spirit's help.